# React - useCallback vs useState's setState(prevState... difference for accessing previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know that useCallback recreates a function when its dependencies change, so it is some kind of wrapper for memoizing functions, useful for accessing the most updated state in useEffects callbacks (for example).

My question here is simple. Is there any difference **for accessing the most freshed state value** between using `useCallback(() => {}, [carData])` and `` setCarData(prevCarData => console.log(`Most freshed state: ${JSON.stringify(prevCarData)}`); ``

I mean, can I get into troubles with the second way? Or the only difference is the memoization of the function?

### UPDATE

A)

```
const memoizedFunc = useCallback(() => {
     ...
      setCarData({...carData, maxVelocity: 50});
}, [carData]);

useEffect(() => {
   if (!carData.maxVelocity) {
      memoizedFunc();
   }
}, [..., memoizedFunc]);
```

B)

```
const func = () => {
    setCarData((prevCarData) => ({...prevCarData, maxVelocity: 50}));
};

useEffect(() => {
   if (!carData.maxVelocity) {
       func();
   }
}, [...]);
```

Thank you.

Comment: `useState` and `useCallback` serve two ***entirely*** different purposes. What are you trying to do? The function passed to `useState` is a "lazy" state initializer that is only called once (*maybe you meant the returned state update function that can take a functional update callback?*). `useCallback` says right in the docs, is useful for passing stable function references as callback, be that in an `useEffect` or passed to children as props.

Comment: I assume you mean `useEffect`, not `useState`?

Comment: useCallback is useful to get the most up-to-date state in a useEffect callback

Comment: also, if in a useEffect callback you use useState(prevState => ... without wrapping this in a useCallback you can access it (the most up-to-date)

Comment: Are you commenting on your own question as if you were a different person...? I *just* woke up, I haven't had any coffee yet, what is this here?

Comment: Thats what I mean. In my use case I am using the second way, to avoid shallow comparing a complex object in the useCallback dependency with the first way. That is why I am asking if the second way can have a chance to get no freshed values.

Comment: I suggest going back and re-reading the documentation for `useEffect`, `useCallback` (which is really just a wrapper around `useMemo`), and `useState`. You've referred to ```useState(prevState => console.log(`Most freshed state: ${JSON.stringify(prevState)}`);``` more than once, but that isn't what that does. You've confused `useState` (the hook) with the state *setter function* that it returns. Passing a function to `useState` serves a completely different purpose (avoiding re-creating expensive initial state objects over and over).

Comment: @ChrisG mmm nope

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry for that. I refer to the setter of the useState hook, but I write this like this to refer to the hook and not to this.setState

Comment: @VictorMolina - That makes the question **very** confusing and unclear. I would suggest instead showing two short code blocks of the two things you're asking people to compare.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder done. Maybe I am not understanding these hooks correctly. But A) and B) seems to work the same way for accessing the most freshed state value in the useEffect callback.

Comment: We need more context because it doesn't make much sense what you're doing in both cases.

Comment: @jperl if func() is called inside the useEffect when one of its dependencies change, setting the car data like this {...carData, velocity: 50} without the useCallback hook or the functional update will cause the use of outdated status

Comment: @Victor Molina you can't rely on carData anyway because setCarData will update carData's value and as a consequence setCarData will be executed again because carData changed, on and on again. If you want the most updated state, use setCarData(prevState => ...).

Comment: @jperl yeah sorry for that loop didn't see it because was a fast example. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean, can I get into troubles with the second way?

No. You're much more likely to get into trouble with A (using `useCallback` for a function you later use in `useEffect`). You're not at all likely to get into trouble with B (using [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)).

---

Beware that [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) (like [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)) doesn't **guarantee** that it won't recreate the function if the dependencies don't change. It's a *performance optimization*, not a semantic guarantee. Your combination of `useCallback` and `useEffect` may cause the effect function to run even when nothing other than the callback has changed, and changed simply because React decided to forget the old version. See the warning on `useMemo`:

> **You may rely on `useMemo` as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.** In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without `useMemo` — and then add it to optimize performance.

*(their emphasis)*

This applies to `useCallback` too, because as they say at the very end of the [`useCallback` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback):

> `useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the first approach you will be creating a different callback every time `carData` changes, which in turn rerenders any hook/component that you pass the callback as a prop.

A better approach would be to utilize `setCarData` implicit `prevState` to avoid such unnecessary rerender.